# saving elasticsearch shard per ssd parallel

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, indexing

I'm testing for performance of elasticsearch.
I read that by using `path.data` config, io performanc could be increased.
So, I thought by setting path.data to multiple ssd path, indexing performance could be increased.
But it was equal with single path config.
Because 2 shards are written in same ssd, there were nothing better.
Should I set other config options to use multiple ssd parallel?
Or should I use multiple instance to use multiple ssd parallel on single machine?
Help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple ssd disks on single machine or just one?

Comment: multiple ssd on single machine and I set path.data to each ssd path but whole shards are saved in one ssd path.

Comment: Are you sure your bottleneck is Disk IO?
My be something else is limiting the performance.

Comment: I think so too, but I have no idea yet.

Comment: If you install `XPack` you will have very cool monitoring dashboards in `kibana` and then you can see what is your bottleneck.